# angles in triangles

Tags: geometry

In the triangle shown, for $\angle A$ to be the largest angle of the triangle, it must be that $m<x<n$. What is the least possible value of $n-m$, expressed as a common fraction? [image: The diagram of the triangle]

Answer (score 3):

HINT.

$x+9$ must be the largest side. But it must also be less than the sum of the other two sides, by triangular inequality.